# Royalslider JavaScript slider.next()

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I user Royalslider and simply want to create a button that goes to the next image.

Here's my code:

```
<button id="slider-next">Next</button>

<script id="addJS">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var slider = $('.royalSlider').royalSlider({
    // options...
            keyboardNavEnabled: true,
            navigateByClick: false,
            sliderDrag: false,
            imageScaleMode: 'fill',

}).data('royalSlider');

$('#slider-next').click(function() {
    slider.next();
});  
});
```

Is there any obvious thing that I've missed?

Comment: what is the issue? What error do you get?

Comment: have you forgotten the closing </script> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the comma after `imageScaleMode: 'fill',`